# Как сократить имя столбца и дать ему название одновременно?

Tags: mysql

То есть можно ли написать что-то подобное

```
SELECT `Дата заключения` дз AS Подписан FROM table...
```

Чтобы использовать "дз" для дальнейших манипуляций в `SELECT` и при этом на выходе получить название столбца "Подписан".

Comment: Нет. Поле выходного набора не может иметь два алиаса.

Comment: В некоторых случаях возможно похожее сокращение без подзапроса/CTE за счёт использования UDV - но нужен текст конкретного запроса, а не "вообще".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `дз` AS `Подписан`, ...
FROM (SELECT `Дата заключения` AS `дз`, ...
      FROM ... ) subquery, ...
...
```

либо то же самое в CTE.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю:

```
SELECT `Дата заключения` as `дз` FROM table...
WHERE `дз` > 0
```

И дам совет на будущее. Название полей и таблиц лучше всего писать на латинице

Comment: Так на выходе будет столбец с именем "дз". А надо чтобы там был "Подписан". При этом в самом селекте не писать постоянно `Дата заключения`, а сократить до "дз"

Comment: Это будет "поле не найдено". Алиас поля выходного набора может быть использован только в GROUP BY/HAVING/ORDER BY.

Comment: @Owl тогда не получится, через `as` вы либо обращаетесь и выводите "дз", либо "подписан"

Comment: @ВладиславВешневский в этом и вопрос

Comment: @Owl *Так на выходе будет столбец с именем "дз". А надо чтобы там был "Подписан".* У меня создаётся суровое впечатление, что именно "Подписан" Вам нужно для ОТОБРАЖЕНИЯ на стороне КЛИЕНТА. Если так - то это на стороне клиента и надо решать.